# Как обработать нажатие аппаратной кнопки Home?

Tags: android, java

Всем доброго. Возможно ли обработать нажатие на аппаратную кнопку Home? Если нет, то, может, как-то можно достоверно узнать, что приложение будет свернуто?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кнопку home нельзя отслеживать и перехватывать. Самый надежный способ отследить, что приложение свернуто - это иметь одно активити, а все реализовывать через фрагменты, тогда при вызове у активити метода onPause(), вы точно будете знать, что приложение свернуто.

Если порыться в тырнете, то предлагают использовать метод [onUserLeaveHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()), но у меня не вышло его использовать, да и в описании сказано, что он вызывается, когда активити уходит в фон при действиях пользователя, а это не всегда ваш случай.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал так: обрабатывал OnPause, и там проверял публичную переменную, которая всегда True, и False только при переходе на другие активности. Иными словами, True она будет только в случае сворачивания приложения. Вообще, мне кажется, мой способ костыльно-велосипедный и не надо так делать. onUserLeaveHint() не подходит, так как нужно остановить MediaPlayer, а если мне позвонят и активити свернется в фон, а я обработал onUserLeaveHint(), то во время разговора я буду слышать чудесную музыку своего приложения, что не кошерно.

Comment: кнопку home можно перехватить. двумя способами.

1. сделать свое прилоежние лаунченом. И один раз помочь пользователю его выбрать по умолчанию. Тогда по нажатию home будет запускаться приложение, что собственно и позволит сделать все, что нужно.
2. переписать прошивку под себя.

Comment: Мне кажется, что если объявить приложение лаунчером, то с этим будут некоторые проблемы у пользователей с установленным кастомным лаунчером, каким-нибудь там Go-launcher'ом.

Answer (score 0):

У Activity и Фрагментов вызовется метод onPause().

Comment: `onPause` вызывается не только при нажатии `HOME`... **Жырный** минус

Comment: @Barmaley, жи-ши пиши через и. И то, что onPause вызывается не только по Home, я знаю. Возможно, логика подходила бы автору.